# no matching state found in storage

Tags: angular, openid-connect

I have CRM application developed in Angular 
I have been facing the error "no matching state found in storage" in chrome and firefox browsers in Australia, Denmark & China regions. But this application works fine USA, India, and Bahamas [image]

Comment: We are experiencing this same error with [vuex-oidc](https://github.com/perarnborg/vuex-oidc/) package, that is a wrapper for [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) package. Several people have been reporting similar issues [Error: No matching state found in storage #93](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/93) and [Machine-wide "No matching state found in storage" #832](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/832), and often with Azure App Service deployment involved.

Comment: Was your site deployed to Azure?

Comment: I am having this problem on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

Comment: @codeMonkey-I am having this problem on Firefox, but not on Chrome? dis you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using angular 5 and identityserver4.

This is because of the time mismatch between system time and that region time.

System time should not be more than five minutes different than the actual regional time. It can be off by showing up to five minutes earlier or up to five minutes later than regional time.

This issue got fixed once the system time is corrected.

I heard this issue got fixed in angular 6 and the latest version of identityserver4

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this today. Double check your URL and make sure its calling a known page.

from

```
https://something.something.com/something.html#234sdfv-23kjlasdkfj
```

to

```
https://something.something.com/something.html
```